# facebook connect php sdk problems in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter-2

I am having problems with the facebook connect php library. Basically on return url my user is 0. Here is my code:

```
public function facebook_login()
{
    $params = array(
        'appId' => 'XXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXX',
        'cookie' => TRUE
    );
    $facebook = $this->load->library('facebook', $params);

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if (empty($user))
    {
        $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            "redirect_uri" => site_url('/auth/facebook/connect') 
                ));
        header("Location: $url"); 
        exit; 
    }
}

public function facebook_connect()
{
    $params = array(
        'appId' => 'XXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXX',
        'cookie' => TRUE
    );
    $facebook = $this->load->library('facebook', $params);

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    print_r($user);die;
}
```

$user is always 0 on the return url. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

go to `config/config.php` and replace;

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = False;
```

with

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

refresh and see the **magic**
hope it helps!